# MySQL - Problema de rendimiento, alto consumo de CPU

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu, rendimiento

En nuestra empresa tenemos un problema de rendimiento con MySQL, el consumo de CPU por parte del mysqld llega al 345% y no sabemos por qué. No hemos realizado ninguna parametrización específica del servicio y tampoco sabemos cómo monitorizar las consultas que se hacen.

[image: Uso de CPU de mysql]

[image: Características CPU]

[image: Sistema Operativo del equipo]

También hemos probado a, sabiendo el indicador de proceso del MySQL, ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
pidstat -t -p INDICADOR_DE_PROCESO l
```

Viendo de esta forma los subprocesos que más CPU estaban utilizando pero no encontramos la forma de buscar qué consultas están ejecutando estos procesos.

Como veis estamos un poco perdidos, ¿alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

Comment: seria necesario ver que tipo de querys se hacen para poder responder.

Comment: En una sesión de MySQL -preferentemente con `root`- ejecuta: `show full processlist;`

Comment: MySQL Workbench proporciona un acceso completo a la base de datos incluidos algunos dashboard de performance en los cuales también puedes ver las conexiones de los clientes. [Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY7Ei.png)

Comment: He ejecutado el comando `show full processlist;` y he visto las queries que se están ejecutando en ese momento pero no tengo forma de saber cuál es la que causa el problema, gracias por vuestras respuestas.